# Is it easy to create gridview for picture with links?

Tags: jquery, gridview, sharepoint-2010, image

I need to create a view like below. Not sure what this view called. I seen somewhere calling this view Grid. I have a sharepoint site with picture library. The library has bunch of pictures with hyperlink column and active (y/n) column.

How easy it going to be in order to create a view like below in sharepoint? I am not looking for visual studio project based solution. I am down for jquery or whatever other easy way to accomplish this. Please suggest.

Here is a sample view
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/2acLM.png

Comment: Looks to me that you need a Repeater. At least that's how I'd implement this in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the Content Query Web Part to show images out.
Then, use CSS (make those images float:left) and fix the Content Query Web Part's width to make a 3 column picture album.
Please refer to this question and the answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34052/getting-last-three-images-with-xsllistviewwebpart/34072#34072

Comment: Thank you Jony. I hope it works the way they are requiring it. btw, I am using sp2010.

Comment: It will works for SP 2010. Don't forget to set a fix width for each image by css style, then images will wrap to columns. Good luck!

Comment: Is there a way display alone with the pictures. (like Title or any other columns)

Comment: You can specify Title, Description, ImageUrl, and LinkUrl columns. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497457.aspx

Comment: Actually, dont have to export and modify the webpart. In the presentation properties, i set the group style to be banded and Item style "image on top". perfectly worked for my situation. Thanks Jony